# Can a getJSON url string be dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, getjson

Is it possible to replace this approach for the url string:

```
    $.when($.getJSON(url0), $.getJSON(url1), $.getJSON(url2), $.getJSON(url3)).then(function() { ...
```

using another JSON file?

Why? The number of url items changes and I want to pull them from a single file without revising where this code lives each time. I could be dealing with url0-url3 or url0-40 then backto url0-url20.

The current approach forces a manual update of the array that's used to build the url string plus an update to the function.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var urls = [
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/18',
  'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/37'
];

var results = {};

function saveResult(urlPath, data) {
  results[urlPath] = data;
}

function f() {
  ($.when).apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(urlPath) {
    return $.getJSON(urlPath, saveResult.bind(this, urlPath));
  })).then(function() {
   console.log('Completed fetch', results); 
  });
}

f.apply(this, urls);
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to grab the urls from a file, something like this should work:

```
function makeUrls(cb) {
  var urls = [];
  var idString1 = '???', idString2 = '????';
  $.when($.getJSON('new_name2.json')).then(function(c) {
    $.each(c.myStuff, function(f, e) {
      urls.push(idString1 + e.id + idString2);
    });
    cb(urls);
  });
}

var results = {};

function saveResult(urlPath, data) {
  results[urlPath] = data;
}

function f() {
  ($.when).apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(urlPath) {
    return $.getJSON(urlPath, saveResult.bind(this, urlPath));
  })).then(function() { console.log('DID IT!', results); });
}

makeUrls(function(urls) {
  f.apply(this, urls);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Threw an undefined on first pass but will try again.

Comment: No joy. If you've tried this before, do you have a fiddle by chance? Thanks!

Comment: Woops, forgot to convert arguments to an array. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this evening and be back to you.

Comment: Ah, this is working! But, I'm not sure how to replace your static array of urls with a getJSON call to a file that I use to build the url strings I use now.

It looks like this:

`$.getJSON("new_name2.json", function(c) {
       data = c;
       $.each(c.myStuff, function(f, e) {
       var urlNEW = idString1+ e.id + idString2;
       console.log(urlNEW);
       });  
     });`

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to get the urls from a file first, then invoke the chained getJSON? I added an example that should work for that scenario above.

Comment: Exactly. This looks promising and i think we are very close. I caught the string2 var typo in the example and ran. But, we're throwing errors: GET http://localhost/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) seems to be the cause. Thanks again for the help and tenacity here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72961/discussion-between-user1452893-and-mfors).